# Welding a ContentPart having a ContentField

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to Weld my custom ContentPart `SitesPart` containing a ContentField of type TaxonomyField but it is not working for me. When i attach this part from UI it works perfectly fine and i see the TaxonomyField in edit mode as well as in display mode.

Following is the Activating method of my ContentHandler.

```
protected override void Activating(ActivatingContentContext context)
{
    if (context.ContentType == "Page")
    {
        context.Builder.Weld<SitesPart>();
    }
}
```

I tried to go deep into the `Weld` function and found out that it is not able to find correct typePartDefinition. It goes inside the condition `if (typePartDefinition == null)` which creates an empty `typePartDefinition` with no existing ContentFields etc.

```
// obtain the type definition for the part
var typePartDefinition = _definition.Parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PartDefinition.Name == partName);
if (typePartDefinition == null) {
    // If the content item's type definition does not define the part; use an empty type definition.
    typePartDefinition = 
        new ContentTypePartDefinition(
               new ContentPartDefinition(partName),
               new SettingsDictionary());
}
```

I would be highly thankful for any guidance.

Comment: Can you show the code for SitesPart?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you are totally right, the part is welded but if there are some content fields, they are not welded. The `ContentItemBuilder` try to retrieve the part definition through the content type definition on which we want to add the part. So, because it's not possible, a new content part is created but with an empty collection of `ContentPartFieldDefinition`...

I think that the `ContentItemBuilder` would need to inject in its constructor and use a `ContentPartDefinition` or more generally an `IContentDefinitionManager`... But, for a quick workaround I've tried the following that works

In ContentItemBuilder.cs, replace this

```
public ContentItemBuilder Weld<TPart>()...
```

With

```
public ContentItemBuilder Weld<TPart>(ContentPartDefinition contentPartDefinition = null)...
```

And this

```
new ContentPartDefinition(partName),
```

With

```
contentPartDefinition ?? new ContentPartDefinition(partName),
```

And in you part handler, inject an `IContentDefinitionManager` and use this

```
protected override void Activating(ActivatingContentContext context) {
    if (context.ContentType == "TypeTest") {
        var contentPartDefinition = _contentDefinitionManager.GetPartDefinition(typeof(FruitPart).Name);
        context.Builder.Weld<FruitPart>(contentPartDefinition);
    }
}
```

Best

Answer (score 0):

To attach a content part to a content type on the fly, you can use this in your handler

```
Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<YourContentPart>("YourContentType"));
```

There are many examples in the source code

Best

Comment: This is technically correct but sadly doesn't solve the problem.
I opened a github issue for it here: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/5197

The fields simply don't show up if the part is welded on like this.